# Want to make user download some files after in-app purchase?

Tags: android, download, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have created an android app, in that i make users download some videos before opening it. Now after some videos they are redirected to in-app purchase where they have to pay to acquire full version. Now i have successfully completed in-app purchase process from [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) now after user payment is successful then it should start downloading other videos in his SD Card.

Please help me with pseudo code or something like that as i am new to in app purchase proces.

Comment: Guys i thought that someone might help me out but still no reply i dont know what to do....

Comment: please help me out guys....